# Lua question: Why my program didnt change the "s" variable?

Tags: lua, var, roblox

The code:

```
local s

if script.Parent.Owned1 == true then
    s = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("PurchasedCars")
else
    s = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("ShopCars")
end

cost = s[script.Parent.Name].Cost
name = s[script.Parent.Name].Named
own = s[script.Parent.Name].Owned

script.Parent.Named.Text = name.Value
script.Parent.Cost.Text = cost.Value

if own.value == true then
    script.Parent.Owned.Text = "✓"
    script.Parent.Owned.TextColor3 = Color3.new(0,255,0)
end
```

I still can't figure out this problem

I still can't figure out this problem for 2 weeks. I'm changed it
I tried to change the program as best I could, but it didn't help - the error remained

Answer (score 0):

I'm fixed the problem:

```
local s
if game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopCars:FindFirstChild(script.Parent.Name) then
s = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("ShopCars")
elseif game.ReplicatedStorage.PurchasedCars:FindFirstChild(script.Parent.Name) then
s = game.ReplicatedStorage:FindFirstChild("PurchasedCars")
end
```